# Automatic run a JavaScript when there is a new data get by Ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

Now I have two javascript, one is I called auto_refresh.js which I use ajax to continuously get new data from mysql database (This part is done).

auto_refresh.js

```
var mainDisplayCacheData;
var mainDisplayData = $('.aside').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_display.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: mainDisplayData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(mainDisplayData){
            if(mainDisplayData !== mainDisplayCacheData){
                mainDisplayCacheData = mainDisplayData;
                $('.aside').html(mainDisplayData);
            }
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

display.php

```
<div class="aside">
  <?php
    $tm = TicketManager::getInstance();
    $tm->displayMainTicket();
    $ticket = $tm->mainTicketSound();
  ?>
</div>
```

ticketmanaget.inc

```
public function mainTicketSound()
{
    $conn = DBManager::getConnection();

    $query = "SELECT queue_id, ticket_name FROM queue
              WHERE DATE(response_time) = DATE(NOW())
              ORDER BY response_time DESC
              LIMIT 1
              ";

    $results = @$conn->query($query);
    if ($results === FALSE or $results === NULL)
      throw new DatabaseErrorException($conn->error);

    if ($results->num_rows < 1)
    {
        $results->close();  
    }
    else
    {
        while($rows = @$results->fetch_array())
        {
            $ticketname = $rows['ticket_name'];
            return $ticketname;
        }
    }

}
```

audio function

```
var input = "<?php echo $ticket; ?>";

            var files = ["0.mp3", "1.mp3",
                         "2.mp3", "3.mp3",
                         "4.mp3", "5.mp3",
                         "6.mp3", "7.mp3",
                         "8.mp3", "9.mp3"];
            var audio = document.createElement("audio");

            var audioIdx = 0;
            var playById = function (id) {
                audio.src = files[input[id]];
              audio.play();
            };

            audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
              audioIdx++;
              if (audioIdx >= files.length) audioIdx = 0;
              playById(audioIdx);
            });

            audio.src = files[input[audioIdx]];
            audio.play();
```

Then I have another script which is used to play audio files. Exactly which files to play is based on the new data get by ajax from database. In my case, I want my second script run the files based on the variable $ticket.

The audio script is done and run perfectly. However, it only play the sound when I refresh the page. I need it to run automatically when the auto_refresh.js get new data. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify where do you get that `$tm` variable from ?

Comment: Ok, question updated.

Comment: If you use this logic won't your HTML file play a new video even if the first has run half? Have you handled this case?

Comment: @gary it is used for a queue system, the counter staff call next number then the sound plays..so it will be just few second for each play and it is under control by the staff (wait the sound finished then only click next)...though it might still happen crash when more than one counter click next at the same time..I am willing to accept any good suggestion for this issue

Comment: @littlecoder I just asked since you used a set time out. Thats all. Technically you should handle this on click event. Create a play function within the success of ajax that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help "big picture".

Note that the code in `display.php` only runs one time - when page initially loads. You need that code to run each time new data is received.

Therefore, you must create a new php file that accepts via POST the new data, and returns (via `echo` not `return`) the desired $ticket value. Call this page as an AJAX call inside the success function of the first AJAX call. Something like this:

**auto_refresh.js**

```
var mainDisplayCacheData;
var mainDisplayData = $('.aside').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_display.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: mainDisplayData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(mainDisplayData){
            if(mainDisplayData !== mainDisplayCacheData){
                mainDisplayCacheData = mainDisplayData;
                $('.aside').html(mainDisplayData);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'new_php_file.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: mainDisplayData,
                    success: function(axData){
                        var files = ["0.mp3", "1.mp3",
                                     "2.mp3", "3.mp3",
                                     "4.mp3", "5.mp3",
                                     "6.mp3", "7.mp3",
                                     "8.mp3", "9.mp3"];

                        //below element already exists. You should update it rather than creating another
                        var audio = document.createElement("audio");

                        var audioIdx = 0;
                        var playById = function (id) {
                            audio.src = files[axData[id]]; //axData returned by AJAX
                          audio.play();
                        };

                        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                          audioIdx++;
                          if (audioIdx >= files.length) audioIdx = 0;
                          playById(audioIdx);
                        });
                        audio.src = files[input[audioIdx]];
                        audio.play();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

**new_php_file.php**

```
<?php
    $new_data = $_POST['mainDisplayData'];

    //insert code required to run lines that follow, and/or modify as required
    $tm = TicketManager::getInstance();
    $tm->displayMainTicket();
    $ticket = $tm->mainTicketSound();
    echo $ticket;
```

Comment: sorry for insufficient information, I have updated the post with added audio function...please let me know if more info needed... btw your solution looks good, I will try it, thanks

Comment: and FYI, the code in display.php keeps running except for the line "$ticket = $tm->mainTicketSound(); it means i can get the new data from $tm->displayMainTicket continuously without needed to refresh the page, but the audio cant

Comment: Made a quick update to answer, just to get you started. Hopefully you can figure out how to edit it to make it work. Good wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Call the sound playing function in the other script in this block:

```
if(mainDisplayData !== mainDisplayCacheData){
  // e.g. otherScriptFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. *On the Server-side*: You should echo the "$ticket" variable.
2. *On the Client-side*: Call your sound playing function inside the 'success' ajax callback:

> ```
> if(mainDisplayData !== mainDisplayCacheData){
>   PLAY_SOUND(mainDisplayData);
> }
> ```